# Error while playing video in Flutter & POD player

Tags: flutter, youtube, podplayer

I have education app created with Flutter and POD player
the last release was published before 4 months, and every things was working fine till 4 days before
suddenly when our students open the app every thing working fine, and all data recieved from server succefuly like: sign in, courses names, images, lectures list
except when I try to open any video, it loading for some seconds, and get message
((Error while playing video))
I try to check the database. upgrade host plan, delete some lectures and register it again

This error happen to some of users not all, and some times not all the time

any ideas about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for some of days of, we find that, suddenly POD Player has stopped because some libraries need to update
we updated the libraries and publish a new release, now all things working fine

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer , its my issue

But still not working with version 0.1.2

the following error comes

```
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632): Playback error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):   com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:644)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:616)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):   Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:413)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:263)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1005)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:412)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/ExoPlayerImplInternal( 3632):       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/flutter ( 3632): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Video player had error com.google.androi
d.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error, null, null)
E/flutter ( 3632): #0      PodPlayerController._checkAndWaitTillInitialized (package:pod_player/src/controllers/pod_player_controller.dart:73:9)
E/flutter ( 3632): #1      PodPlayerController._checkAndWaitTillInitialized (package:pod_player/src/controllers/pod_player_controller.dart:82:11)
E/flutter ( 3632): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3632): #2      PodPlayerController._checkAndWaitTillInitialized (package:pod_player/src/controllers/pod_player_controller.dart:82:5)
E/flutter ( 3632): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 3632): #3      PodPlayerController._checkAndWaitTillInitialized (package:pod_player/src/controllers/pod_player_controller.dart:82:5)
E/flutter ( 3632): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: It is not an answer. Looks like "me too" comment

Comment: when I tried to update my project, find that all 0.1.X pod player versions are stopped.
You need to update it to 0.2.0 or to the latest version 0.2.1 and all related libraries